# Converting numbers in a String list to a int in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do I convert this list...
list = ['1', 'hello', 'bob', '2', 'third', '3', '0']

To this list..
list = [1, 'hello', 'bob', 2, 'third', 3, 'N/A']

or

list = [1, 2, 3, 'N/A']

Basically I am **scraping** data to a list and I need the number from that list & I need to convert all Zero's into N/A. I have tried looping thru the list and replacing it and I get different type errors.

```
for i in list:
    if int(list[i]) == 0:
        call_list[i] = 'N/A'
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

If anyone could help, that would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Did you mean: `if i == '0':`?

Comment: Don't call a list `list`!

Comment: Hahaha Thank you Samwise I thought about that but I wanted to make it clear that it was a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your main issue here is that you don't know that `str.isdigit()` exists, which tests whether a string represents a number (i.e. you can convert it to a number without hitting a `ValueError`.

Also, if you want to iterate over the *indices* in a list, you have to do `for i in range(len(your_list))`, instead of `for element in your_list`. Python uses *for-each* loops, unlike languages like C, and the built-in function `range()` will just produce a list of numbers from 0 to whatever its argument is (in this case, `len(your_list)`) which you can iterate over and use as indices.

```
lst = ['1', 'hello', 'bob', '2', 'third', '3', '0']

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i].isdigit():
        lst[i] = int(lst[i])
        if lst[i] == 0:
            lst[i] = 'N/A'

print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, and you are 100% correct I did not know about isdigit(). When I implemented this it worked beautifully. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach is to define a function that says what you want to do with each item:

```
def convert(item):
    try:
        return int(item) or 'N/A'
    except ValueError:
        return None  # or the original item?
```

and then use the function to build your new list:

```
>>> data = ['1', 'hello', 'bob', '2', 'third', '3', '0']
>>> [convert(d) for d in data if convert(d) is not None]
[1, 2, 3, 'N/A']
```

Note that if you change the last line of the function to `return item`, you can keep the original versions of the items that don't convert into ints:

```
>>> def convert(item):
...     try:
...         return int(item) or 'N/A'
...     except ValueError:
...         return item
...
>>> [convert(d) for d in data]
[1, 'hello', 'bob', 2, 'third', 3, 'N/A']
```

Comment: Thank you for this!! I have not implemented it but I am going to try it out. This looks like a brilliant solution as well because I can just run the lists thru a function. this would be very effective.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom conversion function which can deal with you specific requirements and then use it for list comprehension.

```py
mylist = ['1', 'hello', 'bob', '2', 'third', '3', '0']

def convert(text: str):
  try:
      i = int(text)
  except (TypeError, ValueError):
      return text
  return "N/A" if i==0 else i

new_list = [convert(x) for x in mylist]
new_list2 = [x for x in new_list if isinstance(x, int) or x=='N/A']
```

Answer (score 1):

using a list comprehension that checks if an item is a digit but not a zero
if it is, it converts it to int,
otherwise it checks if it is zero
and converts it to 'N/A'
and finaly keeps everything else intact

```
l =['1', 'hello', 'bob', '2', 'third', '3', '0']
print ([int(item) if item.isdigit() and item != '0' else 'N/A' if item == '0' else item for item in l])
```

outputs:
`[1, 'hello', 'bob', 2, 'third', 3, 'N/A']`

or the same in a bit more readable form

```
print ([
        int(item) if item.isdigit() and item != '0' 
        else 'N/A' if item == '0' 
        else item 
        for item in l
])
```

Comment: close, but doesn't handle `'N/A'`!

Comment: fixed handling of N/A